# Detecting TCP/IP connection drop issues in my application

Tags: networking, tcp, tcpip

I have a desktop application which talks to a server using TCP/IP. It was working before but now we are running into an issue. The log message on the server shows that the socket is disconnected after a while, but we are able to exchange heartbeat messages. When I ran the Wireshark tool I get this log which I don't know how to interpret:

```
4324    36.613058   50.19.123.218   192.168.1.135   
    TCP 843 > bvcontrol [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0

6312    61.546839   50.19.123.218   192.168.1.135   
    TCP 843 > nmsd [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
```

The other thing is when I run this application in the LAN where the server is running it just works fine.

Please help me to understand what is happening in the network.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information here to understand what's really happenning, but you might want to have a look for a stateful firewall between 50.19.123.218 and 192.168.1.135. Also check if you've got keepalives enabled on the client.